# How do I query SQL data then insert or update depending on the result

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner at this. But let me explain what I need to do and show you my code

1. I have a CSV file. 
   inside the CSV I have a projectnumber, city,state,country
2. I have a SQL table with the same column
3. I want to use vb.net to check if projectnumber exists in sql table 
   if exists then I want to run update statement. 
   if it does not exists then I want to run insert statement.

I have the program working . but I am just wondering if this would be the correct way or my code is some hack way of doing it.

LEGEND:
DTTable is data table with CSV inside

DT is data table with SQL result data

1. First I fill insert all lines in the CSV into a data table

   ```
       Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(sRemoteAccessFolder & "text.csv")
       parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
       parser.ReadLine()
       Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
           DTTable.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())
       Loop
       parser.Close()
   ```
2. then I use oledbdataadapter to run the select query and fill another data table with the result of the select statement

   ```
               SQLString = "select * from tblProjects where ProjectID='" & DTTable.Rows.Item(i).Item("ProjectNumber") & "'"
               da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, Conn)
               da.Fill(dt)
   ```
3. then I run if statement

   ```
   If dt.Rows.Count = 0 then
       SQLString = "INSERT STATEMENT HERE"
       oCmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLString, Conn)
       oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   ```

   `Else 
      SQLString = "UPDATE STATEMENT HERE"
      oCmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLString, Conn)
      oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End if`
4. ALL above code is run inside a for loop, to go through all the lines in the CSV

   For i = 0 To DTTable.Rows.Count - 1

what do you think?
please advise

thank you

Comment: How big (number of lines/rows) is the CSV file and the SQL Table?

Comment: CSV is about 200 lines , and SQL table is about 5000 rows

Comment: Some database have the MERGE function that does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't use .NET. I would import the table into a temp SQL Server table and then write my queries to insert/update data from the temp table to the regular table. This is certainly the way you want to go if the dataset is large.

If this is a process you need to repeat frequently, you could make an SSIS package.

Comment: So if I import it into a temp table . is using data table is OK to do? AKA:  using OleDBdatadapted and DT.fill function?  SQLString = "select * from tblProjects where ProjectID='" & DTTable.Rows.Item(i).Item("ProjectNumber") & "'"
            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, Conn)
            da.Fill(dt)

Comment: If you import into a temp table using SQL Server's import capabilities, you won't have any .NET code and it will all be within SQL Server.

Comment: Ah IC. so SSIS package will do the import of CSV into temp table and also do the compare between temp table and my sql table and insert and update as necessary  using SQL query ... basically SSIS can do all of them is that correct?

Comment: yes, but an SSIS package would automate what you can do manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run the select query using `datareader = command.ExecuteReader()`.  Then:

```
If datareader.Read() then
  'Update query using datareader(0) as a where predicate goes here
ElseIf datareader(0) = Nothing then
  'Insert query goes here
End If
```

I should say, I'm a relative novice too though, so maybe others can suggest a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Indent four spaces for your code block in the StackExchange editor.  :-)

Comment: No problem.  I don't think the `elseif` line is necessary in your code block, just use `else`.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this as well as the SSIS idea

Comment: I would also say; using stored procedures is preferable to putting your query straight into the code.  The syntax for writing and executing stored procedures isn't complicated.